# How to pass an entity via a Web Service

Tags: vb.net, web-services

Is there a way to pass the data as an entity within another entity? What I'm trying to get to is this: I'm passing customer details to my database, via the webmethod : PostData. What I want is to pass details such as name, surname, etc as string, but I want to group some details, like vehicle details to be passed as : vehicle.Manufacturer vehicle.Model... etc The other data that are not group-able will be passed as an ordinary string. Hope that makes sense. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are you using REST Or Jax-ws ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either by `XML or JSON`, so the object that in the part of request will be like in XML :

```
<VehicleEntity>
    <attribute1>value</attribute1>
    <attribute2>value</attribute2>
 </VehicleEntity>
```

or Similarly using JSON

```
VehilceEntity{
 attribute1 :value;
 attribute2 :value;
}
```

Basically it is similar to how you are passing parameter, here it is custom parameter `VehicleEntity`

Comment: So would it be like this?                                   [WebMethod]
   public VehicleEntity Vehicle(VehicleEntity vehicle)
      { vehicle.Model = model;
            vehicle.Manufacturer = manufacturer;}

Comment: No.  I'm just unsure as to what (in this instance) model and manufacturer would be? I haven't declared these anywhere. The way I previously exposed it was like this:                      [WebMethod]
   public string PostVehicle(string Model, string Manufacturer)      But I dont want to expose the parameters like that.  I expect the user to consume the web service in order to pass the data.

Comment: Try this and let me know also.

Comment: I would go with this - i.e. write your own de/serializer. My experience with webservices is to *always* pass endpoint parameters as plainly as possible, especially if multiple kinds of clients will be consuming the service. It is extra plumbing in your code to turn complex objects into strings and vice versa, but at least you can control it without having to fight configuration/deployment issues with object mappers. Don't be afraid to use base64 and byte-based in/out values, and if you use custom xml/JSON for your objects include an object version id (e.g. attribute) for forward-compatibility.